# Phone restarting several times every night

Tags: windows-10-mobile, blu-win-hd

I noticed that phone restarted several times per night when it's charging. I think it started after I upgraded it to Windows 10.
I understand that Windows update can require restarting, but not so often I think. During the day phone is working fine without restarting.

Question is: something wrong with phone or it's okay?

Answer (score 2):

Your phone is fine I may say. The phone restarts automatically after a update.

In order to make this process comfortable Windows restarts and installs updates only when you don't use your phone. It automatically determines the time your phone is not being used. Your phone must have set this during night.

You can change this in Settings.

1. Go to *Settings->Updates & Security->Phone Update*.
2. Select *Advanced Options*.
3. There will be an option **Choose how updates are installed**.
4. You can set this to *Notify to schedule restart* if you don't want your phone to restart automatically.

Comment: I have automatic in this option, so it restarts when phone is't using. I just wonder why these updated installed so often.

Comment: no, not insider. I was insider for Win 10, but this is just usual upgrade from Win 8.1 mobile. I understand updates once a week, but almost every day, it looks strange.

Comment: @Alex That's really strange. I recieve updates once/twice in a month on normal builds.There could be some other issues. Please check if your phone is installing the same update over and over again. I had that problem once. If so, hard reset is the only option.

Comment: actually several timer every night. How can I check? Does it have some log?

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately there is no logs or history. You should check it manually when your phone is downloading updates. You can do this by viewing the update settings page as soon your phone is connected to a network. Note the update number, install it and again check for updates. If the same update appears again you have to hard reset your phone.

Comment: okay, set to manual: Notify to schedule restart, but it restarted today morning anyway! And: Your device is up to date.

Comment: @Alex Automatic restarts such as that were problems in the early builds. The solution is to perform a hard reset. For information on performing reset see this link. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/wiki/mdlumia-mdsettings/how-to-soft-and-hard-reset-your-windows-phone/4ec36474-c21e-4aec-ad1b-30f3afaf824d

Comment: okay, I made hard reset, but phone continue restarting (several times last night, actually even on the morning, when it's charging).

Comment: @Alex Is your battery loose or something? If not you should probably go to customer care or wait until someone else else comes up with an other solution. I'm sorry Alex but that's all I could do to help.

Comment: I don't know, how to check battery loose? It also has other problem: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/13606/after-sharing-phone-all-night-battery-indicator-almost-zero Probably  I shouldn't buy cheap phone, maybe Lumia is better, or maybe I should go back to Android. Sorry I removed mark as answer, because this it not really answer to my problem.

Comment: @Alex That's ok. The problem might be with the battery. Have you tried cntacting the customer service? Have u tried using an another battery? If not try using an another battery(borrow one from a friend).

Comment: customer service? should I contact Microsoft? I bought from them.

Comment: @Alex Microsoft is just a seller. Contact blu cus care. If that does not work well than try below option. The bill/invoice given at the time of purchase will contain a customer care number. Try contacting them.