# after charging phone all night battery indicator almost zero

Tags: windows-10-mobile, charging, blu-win-hd

but if I restart phone, it shows 100%.

What is this hardware problem or Windows 10?

PS. If phone discharged during the day, all you need just restart it and battery is 100% again!

Comment: have you tried soft resetting the device?

Comment: yes, I made hard reset, no effect.

Comment: if hard reset is also not making any difference, i guess, you'll have to roll back to 8.1. :(

Comment: @Ram, so you think it's Windows problem?

Comment: or there might be an issue with the battery!

Comment: I have another problem with phone: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/13496/phone-restarting-several-times-every-night maybe it's related